# Distribution of kruskal wallis under H0

Tags: model, statistics, probability-distribution, kruskal-wallis

i'm not sure, but i want to check it.

Does the distribution of kruskal wallis under H0 is F(k-1,N-k) ?

I think that's not true.

I think it distrubution with chi square. Can anyone tell me if I'm right?

Comment: any help please?

Comment: please hellp?...

Answer (score 0):

Kruskal Wallis is a Non-Parametric test. The motto of this test is to assume if two samples come from the same distribution. To assume beforehand what the distribution is under the null hypothesis before actually performing this test is invalid.